# how to get the grids in bs3 to stack when screen is smaller than 480px?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

According to the doc, extra small devices Phones (< 768px) grids are horizontal at all times, i.e., never get stacked. I am looking for a way to make the grids to become stacked when the screen is smaller than 480px.

Answer (score 18):

Add "col-xxs" class to your columns:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) { 
   .col-xxs {
      display:block;
      float:none;
      width: 100%
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm using something like this now, `<div class="col-xxs col-xs-6">`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'col-sm-*' class. This is the "small" grid breakpoint, but at less than 768 pixels it will stack..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/75567

Comment: Thanks! How about <480px? Is it possible to get the grids to become stacked only when the screen size is smaller than 480px?

Comment: So are you asking about < 768px or less than < 480px ? What do you want to happen at 768?

Comment: Come to think of it, when the screen size is between 480px and 768px, I prefer to have two columns of span6. And when the screen gets smaller than 480px, the grid should be stacked.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify exactly what you're looking to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a generic 'all cols must be full width on < 480px devices' you could do something like this to save putting additional classes in the mark-up:

```
[class^="col-"], [class*=" col-"] {
    display:block;
    float:none;
    width: 100%;
}
```